# URL Rewriting not working (ubuntu13.10/apache2.4.6)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need your help! (sorry for my bad english)

I try to do url rewriting in my localhost on Ubuntu13.10/Apache2.4.6 ...
I searched a lot of time on internet and problem is always here..

this is my .htaccess (I begin in url rewriting so I don't know if it's ok) :

```
RewriteEngine On
AllowFromAll All
RewriteRule home/   index.php?uc=home
```

and when I go to `127.0.0.1/mywebsite/home/` I have a 404 error.

- My .htaccess is in : mywebsite/.htaccess
- I activated url rewrite with "sudo a2enmod rewrite" and restarted apache.
- I have no error in apache logs
- I read solution who said I have to change AllowOverride to On in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default but I dont have /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file
- I am lost...

Please, I don't know what to do...

After many tests : I think I have a problem of AllowOverride

Comment: where is your htaccess file?

Comment: in mywebsite/.htaccess

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293272/codeigniter-project-requere-index-php-after-moving-from-xampp-to-lamp-on-ubuntu/22299468#22299468

Answer (score 0):

You either need to specify the `RewriteBase`

```
RewriteBase /mywebsite/
RewriteRule home   index.php?uc=home [L]
```

or add it to your rule

```
RewriteRule /mywebsite/home   index.php?uc=home [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I tried this, but I have always same problem : 404 error :/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more like this :

RewriteRule is relative to the RewriteBase, so if your .htacess is in /mywebsite/ folder :

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /home   index.php?uc=home [L]
```

this way it should work, let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

So... If this is not working, let's start by the beginning.

### Find httpd.conf

`LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so` and `AddModule mod_rewrite.c` should be in there, and without comment mark (#)

### In your .htaccess, there is :

```
# The server must follow symbolic links (this can help in some apache versions)
Options +FollowSymlinks

# RewriteEngine activation
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^home$   index.php?uc=home [L]
```

This configuration works on my apache 2.2.22.

The truth is that

`/index.php?uc=home [L]`

points on `http://127.0.0.1/index.php`

instead of `http://127.0.0.1/mywebsite/index.php`

because of the `DocumentRoot` property. On a real domain, or /w a virtualhost pointing on /mywebsite/, `/index.php?uc=home [L]` should work.

Keep in mind that RewriteRule is relative to the `DocumentRoot` and `RewriteBase` can't resolves this problem.

Comment: Really thanks for this big answer... but there's not httpd.conf in apache2.4.6/ubuntu... so I can't do your recommendations...

Comment: Not even in `/home/[user-name]/apache/conf/httpd.conf` ?

Comment: No there no apache folder in /home/[user-name]/ , sorry